# finding the inverse under modular multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra

Question: whats the order of $a=2$ in $U(33)$ under modular multiplication?
$$\langle 2\rangle = \{2,4,8,16,32,31,29,25,17,1\}$$
Therefore $\text{order}(2)=10$

Whats the inverse of $2$ in $U(33)$?
Edit:$17$

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why did you cube $1/2$?  In any case, if you're asked to find the inverse, you can't just write "$1/2$" to mean the inverse of $2$, you have to actually find an element of the group which yields $1$ when multiplied by $2$.

Fortunately, you have a list of numbers, where each one is the previous multiplied by $2$... and $1$ is in that list... hmm...

Comment: Im assuming what I did is wrong...any correction for me?

Comment: @chris Hmm... we're looking for something that gives us $1$ if we multiply it by $2$... and we have a list of numbers that show us how to multiply by $2$... hmm...

Comment: @chris If you're not following my hints, take a look at your own list right here.  The answer is staring at you: $\{2,4,8,16,32,31,29,25,17,1\}$

Comment: So then I shouldn't include 31.29,25,17,1? Am I following you? Or noo

Comment: @chris I have no idea what you're talking about.  The list is fine.  It's a list of what happens if you keep multiplying by $2$.  And you're looking for something, an inverse, which is a number that has a certain property when it's multiplied by $2$.  Maybe your list can tell you what this number is...

Answer (score 0):

Conjecture: I can't add a comment due to a lack of points but I think the inverse is 17, because 2(17) will yield 34=1 mod(33). Since we are looking for an m in Z such that 2m is congruent to 1 mod(33). Please feel free to offer comments